# JQuery multiple show/ hide column DataTables not properly working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to show/hide multiple columns with one checkbox in DataTables with jquery, but the columns did not show again after hide

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" id="cbox1"> Show/Hide <br>

$('#cbox1').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var column = table.columns([10,11]);
        column.visible( ! column.visible());
   }
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d14c2s8k/)

Comment: You need to share more code related to your question. You use `checkbox` to show/hide but the condition to show/hide is `column.visible(!column.visible());`, is it reasonable?

Comment: it is. and its work fine with that when its only one column

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how I did it:

```js
    var table = $('table').DataTable();

    $('#cbox1').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var column = table.columns([2,3]);

        // if checked hide else show
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          column.visible(false);
        } else {
          column.visible(true);
        }
   })
```